# How to search data from multiple tables in grid in yii2.0

Tags: grid, yii2, show

I have two tables like `Customer(id,f_name,l_name)` and `cycle (id,customer_id,cycle_name,address)`.

I am using customer controller for base -grid;
I want to show cyclename in grid view in yii2.

Answer (score 2):

In `Customer` model put relation (but I don't now use for you (`hasOne` or `hasMany`, I will be use `haOne`)):

```
public function getCycle()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Cycle::className(), ['customer_id' => 'id']);
    }
```

In controller:

```
public function actionGrid(){
    $query = Customer::find()->with(['cycle']);
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
                'query' => $query,
            ]);

    return $this->render('grid', [            
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            ]);
}
```

From View use:

```
    <?= \yii\grid\GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'f_name',
            [
                'label' => 'Cycle',
                'value' => function ($data) {
                   return $data->cycle->cycle_name; 
                }
            ]
        ]
    ]); ?>
```